# How to change System.State field in TFS?

Tags: tfs

I have the requirement where I do need to change the `System.State` field of `workitem` when other field gets changed. I know TFS workflow is state-based i.e. depending upon the state you can change values of other fields. But how to go another way around?

- Mayur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve that by using the built-in work item workflow. That's due to the fact that one must use the <COPY> rule in order to set the value of a field. However, you can't use <COPY> with the System.State field. Trying to do so results in the following error:

> TF26062: Rule '<COPY from="value" value="Active" />' is not supported
>   for the field 'System.State'.

That leaves you with two options:

1. Create a custom control. It has the advantage of immediate feedback, but can be very expensive to develop - especially if you can to support WinForms (Visual Studio), Web (Team Web Access) and Java (Eclipse + TEE);
2. Handle it  from the server side, monitoring the WorkItemChanged event. The downside is that it doesn't reflect immediately in the end-user screen. After editing a work item, the user would have to hit Refresh to see the new state.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got the idea of at least what I need to do!

Comment: @MayurLankeshwar Be careful with option 2, it will work, but if you use it too often, it will annoy people to death. We had a similar automation and it happens very often, that someone saves a work item, then the automation changes the status and then the user notices, that he forgot something. He writes down his comment, wants to save and gets the message, that someone else already changed the work item.