# TFS 2010 - Set the State field to a certain value

Tags: xml, workflow, tfs-workitem

I know it's possible to change the values of certain fields using TFS 2010 and the [WHEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194966.aspx) conditional rule, but I am having the following error message when importing my template to TFS 2010:

`TF26062: Rule <COPY from="value" value="Resolved" /> is not supported for the field 'System.State'.`

Here is my XML template code

```
<FIELD name="State" refname="System.State" type="String" reportable="dimension">
  <WHEN field="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork" value="0">
    <COPY from="value" value="Resolved" />
  </WHEN>
  <HELPTEXT>The workflow state of the task</HELPTEXT>
</FIELD>
```

Which translates to: When the field "RemainingWork" equals zero, set the value of the "State" field to "Resolved". Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Does this reference help? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227015/how-to-change-system-state-field-in-tfs

Comment: I haven't seen that, thanks